How to dualize a "categorical property"?
We often say that, given a categorical property, we get a dual property by reversing arrows. Is there a precise sense behind this sentence ? 
What I mean is: for example, given a first order formula of the theory of totally ordered field we easily get it's negation by reverting quantifiers and inequalities. 
Is there something like that for dualizing "categorical properties".
My question can be broken into two parts:

Is there a "categorical language" in which one can express "categorical properties" (for example, existence of limits/colimits (even infinite ones)) ?
Is there a simple algorithm to dualize formulas in this language ?


There are usually multiple ways to dualize one thing. Is the dual of a lax limit an oplax limit or a lax colimit? Or oplax colimit?

Almost identical MO discussion
